# OAuth 2 process starting from Authorization Server instead of client's service

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a OAuth2.0 Authorization Server following the Authorization Code flow ([rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1)) and it is working fine.

Let's summarize the process when a user visits another website (called website A) that implemented a relationship with my authorization server.

1. the user clicks on a link or something
2. he is redirected to my server (on AuthorizeEndpoint) where he can login and give consent to some things
3. back to website A with an authorization code
4. website A exchanges the authorization code with access and refresh tokens then he's able to request an API with his token

My question is: if a user visits **my** website instead of website A, is it ok to take the consents and then to redirect him to the website A with the authorization code even though website A did not do the initial request? In other words, is it ok to "skip" the first step if the user is **already** on my website? Or am I "breaking" the standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and it seems like I **can't** do it because in this context the `state` parameter is unusable so I can't prevent CSRF attacks anymore.